# How can I Modify default images of Navigation Drawer.?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, navigation-drawer

I want to change default Images of Navigation Drawer in Android.When I'm changing it's not working any one help me please.Thanks stack over flow.how can I do this help me please.

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_camera"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
        android:title="Import" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:title="Gallery" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
        android:title="Slideshow" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_manage"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
        android:title="Tools" />
</group>

<item android:title="Communicate">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_share"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
            android:title="Share" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_send"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
            android:title="Send" />
    </menu>
</item>
```

Comment: Is your new image png or vector drawable??

Comment: When you put the images into drawable, make sure there size is not more than 48*48 pixels.

Comment: I want to know both

Comment: After you put a new image, whats the output?? Is it blank??

Comment: Yes, just I'm practicing thats it

Comment: I think we have predefined images in android studio right how can we get it(i'm asking that while we are creating Navigation Drawer activity we get default images like "camera,setting symbol,share symbol.....like that we have right)i wana see that images I think u got it now

Comment: yes after put a new image it's blank only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you need some pre defined vector drawables as one of your comments was pointing to it.

Try

1. **Right Click** drawable folder
2. **New -> Vector Asset**
3. Enable Material Icon RadioButton (enabled by default)
4. Click **Choose** button
5. Select one image. change Resource name if required & click **Next** -> **Finish**.

Now a new vector drawable will be created in drawable folder & you can refer it using **@drawable**.

Comment: Thanks, it working if you want to insert our own images what we have to do

Comment: @CHANDU you can use other images also(PNG recommended). Put that png in drawable & refer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my .xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_home"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_home"
            android:title="section1"
            android:checked="true"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_add_event"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_addevent"
            android:title="section2" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_managenews"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage_news"
            android:title="section3" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_leaderboard"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_leadre_board"
            android:title="section3"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_mypoints"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_mypoint"
            android:title="section4" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_myprofile"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_my_profile"
            android:title="section5" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_change_password"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_change_password"
            android:title="section6"/>
    </group>
</menu>
```

Comment: also change in Activity.java file in menuItemSelected

Comment: where we can get predefined images in android studio

Comment: you  can put your image icon into drawable folder whatever you want to display.

Comment: @ Vishal Patoliya what you are mention that's all are in predefined in android studio right.how can i see hole that much of images

Comment: no above are not predefined in android studio you must put it into drawable folder

Comment: That's fine, I think we have predefined images in android studio right how can we get it(i'm asking that while we are creating Navigation Drawer activity we get default images like "camera,setting symbol,share symbol.....like that we have right)i wana see that images I think u got it now

Comment: I think now also you are not getting me